# How to make post request to a given api

Tags: api, http, post

Assume the url is

```
www.example.com
```

I'm trying to make a post request using Postman to the following API.

`sample1, /sample2, ...,/sample10`

I can't figure out what's that mean. Should I put api as key, and /sample1 in the params? Or put them in the header? Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to provide help.  What exactly is it you're trying to do? are you trying to post 'sample1', 'sample2', and 'sample10' to www.example.com?

Comment: I'm trying to post a header with a pair of key and value to the server, and I should receive one code from each route. I assume sample1 ...sample10 are the route. But I don't how to include that in Postman. Thanks

Comment: Is this API public? If yes, can you attach the link? Otherwise, it would be difficult to understand the problem without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup would be: [image: post man like the image below]

/sample1 sample10 are just parts of the url you're posting to.  To add the header click on the header tab and add a key/value for the headers you want to send.